# How to check if a letter is in a tuple and show the word

Tags: python

```py
tuple = ("Hi", "i am", "new")
letter = input("What letter would you like to find?")
if letter in tuple:
      for x in letter:
            print(x)
```

I don't get anything in the output.

The idea is to ask for a letter, then print the words in the tuple that have the letter.

Comment: What happens if your input is a word, like "Hi"?

Comment: In your onw words, when you do `for x in letter`, what do you intend for that to accomplish? Try to think about your logic clearly and write out the steps first. Physically putting pencil to paper helps for many.

Answer (score 5):

You need to iterate through the words in the tuple.

```py
tuple = ("Hi", "i am", "new")
letter = input("What letter would you like to find?")
for word in tuple:
    if letter in word:
        print(word)
```

Alternate methods that take out some of the looping:

```py
wordList = ("Hi", "i am", "new")
letter = input("Enter letter >>")
print([word for word in wordList if letter in word])
```

Your current code checks if the input is one of the values in the tuple. By adding in that line (`if letter in word`), your program will check if each element in the tuple contains your input.

Answer (score 1):

Try list comprehension to speed things up

```
tup = ("Hi", "i am", "new")
letter = input("What letter would you like to find?")
[s for s in tup if letter in s]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension, like this:

```
tup = ("Hi", "i am", "new")
letter = "i"

print(*[x for x in tup if letter in x], sep="\n")

# Hi
# i am
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the words in the tuple, and check if the letter is contained in each word.

You can use `filter` for that:

(Regardless to your question, you shouldn't override the built-in `tuple`, so the variable name is changed)

```
t = ("Hi", "i am", "new")
letter = input("What letter would you like to find?")
filtered_tuple = list(filter(lambda w: letter in w, t))
```

Comment: You're shadowing the tuple built-in.

Comment: @jorf.brunning you're correct, I copied the OP's code. Fixed it.